# $f: E^3 \rightarrow E^3$ is an isometry, and $\det f = 1$ and $f'\neq id$

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

Suppose, that $f: E^3 \rightarrow E^3$ is an isometry, and $\det f = 1$ and $f'\neq id$

Please help me prove, that $f$ is a composition of rotation about an axis and moving along this axis.

I don't know how to start, but tried to write down the matrix and calculate equations for that. I've got equations with 3 degree...

Thanks for all ideas and help!

*f' is a linear part of f*

Comment: "a linear part of $f$"?

Comment: yes, that mean is a linear transformation connected with affine transformation f

Comment: Hint: Let $f(X)=AX+b$, where $A\in SO(3), b\in E^3$, so $\det A=1$ and $A\neq id$.

Comment: composition of rotation about an axis and moving along this axis? I think it can move along any direction.

Comment: @MaMing, when the translation is not parallel to the axis, we translate the axis of rotation so as to arrange that it will be.